# SPARQL query optimisation

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I'm working on a SPARQL query to be run against the public DBPedia endpoint http://dbpedia.org/sparql and although results are being returned, the query is taking a long time to execute. I am not an expert in SPARQL and was hoping someone could help me optimise the query if possible.

The query retrieves the following:

- property URI
- object URI
- property label
- object label
- object datatype

...if the object label (or object itself if it is a string datatype) contains a key word.

For example, in the query below I am looking for results where the object label (if a label is present) or the object itself (if a string datatype) contains the key word 'London'.

When [running the query against the endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3FpropertyLabel%20%3Fproperty%20%3FobjectLabel%20%3Fobject%20datatype%28%3Fobject%29%20AS%20%3FobjectDataType%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FURI%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fobject%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fobject%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FobjectLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FobjectLabel%20bif%3Acontains%20%27%22London%22%27%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28lang%28%3FobjectLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3FURI%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fobject%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fobject%20bif%3Acontains%20%27%22London%22%27%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fobject%29%20%3D%20%27%27%20%7C%7C%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fobject%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20BIND%28%3Fobject%20AS%20%3FobjectLabel%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fproperty%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FpropertyLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28lang%28%3FpropertyLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20DESC%28count%28%3Fproperty%29%29%20LIMIT%20500) it takes some time to complete. I'm aware that the query completes faster with less generic keywords, but the application sending the keyword to the query will usually send relatively generic keywords so I am hoping the query can be optimised somehow.

Note that I had to use the BIND operation to bind the object URI with the object label as the application using this result data cannot accept a blank value in this field, which occurs when the object is a string datatype.

```
SELECT ?propertyLabel ?property ?objectLabel ?object datatype(?object) AS ?objectDataType 
WHERE
  {
    ?URI ?property ?object .
    {
      ?object       rdfs:label    ?objectLabel .
      ?objectLabel  bif:contains  '"London"' .
         FILTER langMatches(lang(?objectLabel), 'en')
    }
    UNION
    {
      ?URI     ?property     ?object .
      ?object  bif:contains  '"London"' .
         FILTER (  lang(?object) = '' 
                || langMatches(lang(?object), 'en')
                ) .
         BIND(?object AS ?objectLabel)
    }
    ?property  rdfs:label  ?propertyLabel .
       FILTER langMatches(lang(?propertyLabel), 'en') .
  }
ORDER BY DESC(count(?property)) 
LIMIT 500
```

Comment: One reason this takes very long is that you are not really restricting the type of resources you are looking up. Is it literally the case that you want to retrieve _everything_ containing the term 'London' in its label? Or can you be more specific, say by querying only for resources that are Geographical Features, or which have a  `population` property, or....

Comment: Thanks Jeen, yes unfortunately we would need to retrieve everything that contains the key word in its label. I was hoping the query could be optimised to improve the speed but I take your point that the unspecific nature of the keyword is a major factor for the slow speed.

Comment: Well, if it can't be done how it should, then it should be done how it can. I'm not seeing anything obvious to change but a potential idea is to move the `bif:contains` filter into a subselect, and then have the outer query do the knitting together of what the matching variable should connect to. The theory would be that this would allow the endpoint to quickly zoom in on "things about London" (because the inner query gets evaluated first). Whether this will work is conjecture though.

Comment: Note that you could spin up your own mirror of [DBpedia](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07BQKYGYQ) (or of [DBpedia-Live](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B012DSCFEK)) in the AWS cloud and give it much more memory and/or processor (by picking a more powerful instance type) than the machine hosting the public instance, and so speed up the responses you get.